# How do I check if a number is a palindrome?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

How do I check if a number is a palindrome?

Any language. Any algorithm. (except the algorithm of making the number a string and then reversing the string).

Comment: Can you find out the size of integer in bits? if yes,
Say A is the no and s is the size
B = A << s/2
check if A&B == 2^s-1 - 2^(s/2) + 1

Comment: What's wrong with 'making the number a string and then reversing the string'?

Comment: Start by defining what `number` and `is a palindrome` shall mean in this context: how about 13E31(base ten)? 01210(leading zero)? +10-10+1 (five digit balanced ternary)?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

This is [one of the Project Euler problems](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=4).  When I solved it in Haskell I did exactly what you suggest, convert the number to a String.  It's then trivial to check that the string is a pallindrome.  If it performs well enough, then why bother making it more complex?  Being a pallindrome is a lexical property rather than a mathematical one.

Comment: Indeed. Any algorithm you make will have to at least split the number into base-10 digits, which is 90% converted to a string anyway.

Comment: It's definitely a neat trick to convert it to a string but it kind of defeats the point if you were asked this on an interview because the point would be to determine if you understand modulo.

Comment: @Robert Noack - the interviewer can then ask you to describe an algorithm to convert an integer to a string, which of course requires you to understand modulo.

Comment: @Steve314 `to describe an algorithm to convert an integer to a string, which of course requires you to understand modulo` - no. Computing in the target number system, being able to add will do (think how you commonly convert from decimal to binary - being used to think _computation means binary_ doesn't mean you can't do, e.g., _decimal arithmetic_ (and you _can_ do conversion from binary to decimal without division or modulo 2).

Comment: @greybeard - I'm assuming the arithmetic is done on the type that supports arithmetic and the string operations are done on the type that supports string operations - that's division and modulo/remainder for the integer and prepending characters for the string. Of course you *can* implement arithmetic on strings for yourself, but (1) are you really going to? Just to convert an integer to a string?, and (2) though you can handle this (inefficiently) without it, you'll need to understand remainders at some point - you don't have a complete integer arithmetic on strings without that.

Answer (score 281):

For any given number:

```cpp
n = num;
rev = 0;
while (num > 0)
{
    dig = num % 10;
    rev = rev * 10 + dig;
    num = num / 10;
}
```

If `n == rev` then `num` is a palindrome:

```cpp
cout << "Number " << (n == rev ? "IS" : "IS NOT") << " a palindrome" << endl;
```

Comment: that's what i came up w/ too. i guess no sense in me posting it now. +1

Comment: Is this assuming that rev is initialized to zero?

Comment: Yes Justsalt. The rev variable is initialized to zero.

Comment: a method with a little better constant factor:

lastDigit=0;
rev=0;
while (num>rev) {
    lastDigit=num%10;
    rev=rev*10+lastDigit;
    num /=2;
}
if (num==rev) print PALINDROME; exit(0);
num=num*10+lastDigit; // This line is required as a number with odd 
                      // number of will necessary end up being
                      // smaller even if it is a palindrome  
if (num==rev) print PALINDROME

Comment: _Note for passersby:_ if implementing this in a language that would keep the fractional part of `num` after division (looser typing), you'll need to make that `num = floor(num / 10)`.

Comment: This solution is not totally right. variable dig possibly might overflow. For example, I assume the type of num is int, the value is almost Integer.Max, its last digit is 789, when reverse dig, then overflow.

Comment: `rev1` might overflow. Consider input `num = 2147483647`

Comment: Doesn't work for numbers with trailing zeros.

Answer (score 24):

```py
def ReverseNumber(n, partial=0):
    if n == 0:
        return partial
    return ReverseNumber(n // 10, partial * 10 + n % 10)

trial = 123454321
if ReverseNumber(trial) == trial:
    print("It's a Palindrome!")
```

Works for integers only. It's unclear from the problem statement if floating point numbers or leading zeros need to be considered.

Trailing zeros need special treatment.  Any number can be considered to have as many leading zeros as you want, since leading zeros don't make any difference to the value of the number.  When you reverse a number, the trailing zeros turn into leading zeros and are effectively lost.  The solution is to strip those zeros and not consider them in the palindrome check at all.

```
def remove_trailing_zeros(n):
    while n != 0 and (n % 10) == 0:
        n //= 10
    return n

trial = 12345432100
if ReverseNumber(trial) == remove_trailing_zeros(trial):
    print("It's a Palindrome!")
```

Answer (score 24):

Above most of the answers having a trivial problem is that the int variable possibly might overflow.

Refer to [http://articles.leetcode.com/palindrome-number/](https://web.archive.org/web/20180222083908/http://articles.leetcode.com/palindrome-number/)

```java
boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
    if (x < 0)
        return false;
    int div = 1;
    while (x / div >= 10) {
        div *= 10;
    }
    while (x != 0) {
        int l = x / div;
        int r = x % 10;
        if (l != r)
            return false;
        x = (x % div) / 10;
        div /= 100;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Will fail when numbers have zeros in them. Example : 10000021.

Answer (score 13):

```c
int is_palindrome(unsigned long orig)
{
    unsigned long reversed = 0, n = orig;

    while (n > 0)
    {
        reversed = reversed * 10 + n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }

    return orig == reversed;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Push each individual digit onto a stack, then pop them off.  If it's the same forwards and back, it's a palindrome.

Comment: How do you push each individual digit from the integer?

Comment: Something along the lines of:

int firstDigit = originalNumber % 10;
int tmpNumber = originalNumber/10;
int secondDigit = tmpNumber % 10;

.... 

until you're done.

Comment: This won't work in the context of the LeetCode question - no additional space is allowed.

Answer (score 9):

Fastest way I know:

```c
bool is_pal(int n) {
    if (n % 10 == 0) return 0;
    int r = 0;
    while (r < n) {
        r = 10 * r + n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return n == r || n == r / 10;
}
```

Comment: Quite similar to [Toon Krijthe's 2008 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/200193/3789665) (note the difference in the pre-check).

Comment: One could just drop the pre-check...

Answer (score 8):

I didn't notice any answers that solved this problem using no extra space, i.e., all solutions I saw either used a string, or another integer to reverse the number, or some other data structures.

Although languages like Java wrap around on integer overflow, this behavior is undefined in languages like C. (*Try reversing 2147483647 (Integer.MAX_VALUE) in Java*)
Workaround could to be to use a long or something but, stylistically, I don't quite like that approach.

Now, the concept of a palindromic number is that the number should read the same forwards and backwards. Great. Using this information, we can compare the first digit and the last digit. Trick is, for the first digit, we need the order of the number. Say, 12321. Dividing this by 10000 would get us the leading 1. The trailing 1 can be retrieved by taking the mod with 10. Now, to reduce this to 232. `(12321 % 10000)/10 = (2321)/10 = 232`. And now, the 10000 would need to be reduced by a factor of 2. So, now on to the Java code...

```java
private static boolean isPalindrome(int n) {
    if (n < 0)
        return false;

    int div = 1;
    // find the divisor
    while (n / div >= 10)
        div *= 10;

    // any number less than 10 is a palindrome
    while (n != 0) {
        int leading = n / div;
        int trailing = n % 10;
        if (leading != trailing)
            return false;

        // % with div gets rid of leading digit
        // dividing result by 10 gets rid of trailing digit
        n = (n % div) / 10;

        // got rid of 2 numbers, update div accordingly
        div /= 100;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Edited as per [Hardik](/users/3060101/hardik)'s suggestion to cover the cases where there are zeroes in the number.

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun, this one also works.

```c
a = num;
b = 0;
if (a % 10 == 0)
  return a == 0;
do {
  b = 10 * b + a % 10;
  if (a == b)
    return true;
  a = a / 10;
} while (a > b);
return a == b;
```

Comment: (Would upvote but for missing documentation and not mentioning a language specification to give exact meaning to the code presented.)

Answer (score 6):

In Python, there is a fast, iterative way.

```py
def reverse(n):
    newnum=0
    while n>0:
        newnum = newnum*10 + n % 10
        n//=10
    return newnum

def palindrome(n):
    return n == reverse(n)
```

This also prevents memory issues with recursion (like StackOverflow error in Java)

Comment: Close, but you're mutating n while doing this. You want to store the original n value and do the return compare using that instead

Comment: @RGroppa, in Python numbers are immutable (as in most programming languages). The caller's `n` will not be influenced. There is no need to do what you suggest.

Answer (score 5):

> except making the number a string and then reversing the string.

Why dismiss that solution? **It's easy to implement and readable**. If you were asked with no computer at hand whether `2**10-23` is a decimal palindrome, you'd surely test it by writing it out in decimal.

In Python  at least, the slogan 'string operations are slower than arithmetic' is actually false. I compared Smink's arithmetical algorithm to simple string reversal `int(str(i)[::-1])`. There was no significant difference in speed - it  happened string reversal was marginally faster.

In compiled languages (C/C++) the slogan might hold, but one risks overflow errors with large numbers.

```py
def reverse(n):
    rev = 0
    while n > 0:
        rev = rev * 10 + n % 10
        n = n // 10
    return rev

upper = 10**6

def strung():
    for i in range(upper):
        int(str(i)[::-1])

def arithmetic():
    for i in range(upper):
        reverse(i)

import timeit
print "strung", timeit.timeit("strung()", setup="from __main__ import strung", number=1)
print "arithmetic", timeit.timeit("arithmetic()", setup="from __main__ import arithmetic", number=1)
```

Results in seconds (lower is better):

> strung 1.50960231881
>   arithmetic 1.69729960569

Answer (score 4):

I answered the Euler problem using a very brute-forcy way. Naturally, there was a much smarter algorithm at display when I got to the new unlocked associated forum thread. Namely, a member who went by the handle Begoner had such a novel approach, that I decided to reimplement my solution using his algorithm. His version was in Python (using nested loops) and I reimplemented it in Clojure (using a single loop/recur).

Here for your amusement:

```clj
(defn palindrome? [n]
  (let [len (count n)]
    (and
      (= (first n) (last n))
      (or (>= 1 (count n))
        (palindrome? (. n (substring 1 (dec len))))))))

(defn begoners-palindrome []
  (loop [mx 0
         mxI 0
         mxJ 0
         i 999
         j 990]
    (if (> i 100)
      (let [product (* i j)]
        (if (and (> product mx) (palindrome? (str product)))
          (recur product i j
            (if (> j 100) i (dec i))
            (if (> j 100) (- j 11) 990))
          (recur mx mxI mxJ
            (if (> j 100) i (dec i))
            (if (> j 100) (- j 11) 990))))
      mx)))

(time (prn (begoners-palindrome)))
```

There were Common Lisp answers as well, but they were ungrokable to me.

Comment: I tried some of the "mathematical" palindrome tests posted here, but was surprised that this string based version was the faster one.

Comment: Maybe this shouldn't be surprising - after all, the fastest way you could realize a number given to you was a palindrome was by reading the first half then reading the second half backwards, not by doing any kind of arithmetic

Answer (score 4):

Here is an Scheme version that constructs a function that will work against any base. It has a redundancy check: return false quickly if the number is a multiple of the base (ends in 0).
And it doesn't rebuild the entire reversed number, only half.
That's all we need.

```lisp
(define make-palindrome-tester
   (lambda (base)
     (lambda (n)
       (cond
         ((= 0 (modulo n base)) #f)
         (else
          (letrec
              ((Q (lambda (h t)
                    (cond
                      ((< h t) #f)
                      ((= h t) #t)
                      (else
                       (let*
                           ((h2 (quotient h base))
                            (m  (- h (* h2 base))))
                         (cond
                           ((= h2 t) #t)
                           (else
                            (Q h2 (+ (* base t) m))))))))))
            (Q n 0)))))))
```

Answer (score 4):

Recursive solution in ruby, without converting the number to string.

```rb
def palindrome?(x, a=x, b=0)
  return x==b if a<1
  palindrome?(x, a/10, b*10 + a%10)
end

palindrome?(55655)
```

Answer (score 3):

Golang version:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    n := 123454321
    r := reverse(n)
    fmt.Println(r == n)
}

func reverse(n int) int {
    r := 0
    for {
        if n > 0 {
            r = r*10 + n%10
            n = n / 10
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    return r
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pop off the first and last digits and compare them until you run out.  There may be a digit left, or not, but either way, if all the popped off digits match, it is a palindrome.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more solution in c++ using templates . This solution will work for case insensitive palindrome string comparison .

```cpp
template <typename bidirection_iter>
bool palindrome(bidirection_iter first, bidirection_iter last)
{
    while(first != last && first != --last)
    {
        if(::toupper(*first) != ::toupper(*last))
            return false;
        else
            first++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

a method with a little better constant factor than @sminks method:

```
num=n
lastDigit=0;
rev=0;
while (num>rev) {
    lastDigit=num%10;
    rev=rev*10+lastDigit;
    num /=2;
}
if (num==rev) print PALINDROME; exit(0);
num=num*10+lastDigit; // This line is required as a number with odd number of bits will necessary end up being smaller even if it is a palindrome
if (num==rev) print PALINDROME
```

Comment: A pity you didn't hyperlink [*@smink*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/199218/3789665): names change. This seems to mix bases 10 and 2, and not for the better.

Answer (score 1):

here's a f# version:

```
let reverseNumber n =
    let rec loop acc = function
    |0 -> acc
    |x -> loop (acc * 10 + x % 10) (x/10)    
    loop 0 n

let isPalindrome = function
    | x  when x = reverseNumber x -> true
    | _ -> false
```

Answer (score 1):

A number is palindromic if its string representation is palindromic:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    return all(s[i] == s[-(i + 1)] for i in range(len(s)//2))

def number_palindrome(n):
    return is_palindrome(str(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def palindrome(n):
    d = []
    while (n > 0):
        d.append(n % 10)
        n //= 10
    for i in range(len(d)/2):
        if (d[i] != d[-(i+1)]):
            return "Fail."
    return "Pass."
```

Answer (score 1):

To check the given number is Palindrome or not (Java Code)

```
class CheckPalindrome{
public static void main(String str[]){
        int a=242, n=a, b=a, rev=0;
        while(n>0){
                    a=n%10;  n=n/10;rev=rev*10+a;
                    System.out.println(a+"  "+n+"  "+rev);  // to see the logic
               }
        if(rev==b)  System.out.println("Palindrome");
        else        System.out.println("Not Palindrome");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I always use this python solution due to its compactness.

```
def isPalindrome(number):
    return int(str(number)[::-1])==number
```

Comment: That is compact, but the OP specifically said "_except the algorithm of making the number a string and then reversing the string_"

Answer (score 1):

```
int reverse(int num)
{
    assert(num >= 0);   // for non-negative integers only.
    int rev = 0;
    while (num != 0)
    {
        rev = rev * 10 + num % 10;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return rev;
}
```

This seemed to work too, but did you consider the possibility that the reversed number might overflow? If it overflows, the behavior is language specific (For Java the number wraps around on overflow, but in C/C++ its behavior is undefined). Yuck.

It turns out that comparing from the two ends is easier. First, compare the first and last digit. If they are not the same, it must not be a palindrome. If they are the same, chop off one digit from both ends and continue until you have no digits left, which you conclude that it must be a palindrome.

Now, getting and chopping the last digit is easy. However, getting and chopping the first digit in a generic way requires some thought. The solution below takes care of it.

```
int isIntPalindrome(int x)
{
    if (x < 0)
    return 0;
    int div = 1;
    while (x / div >= 10)
    {
        div *= 10;
    }

    while (x != 0)
    {
        int l = x / div;
        int r = x % 10;
        if (l != r)
            return 0;
        x = (x % div) / 10;
        div /= 100;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Like it, very considerate. Minuscule nits: init `div = 10`, just loop `while (10 <= x)`, indent the very first `return` and drop the braces around `div *= 10;`. Quite similar to at least [user1552891's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20134388/3789665).

Answer (score 1):

```
//check whether a number is palindrome or not in Javascript
let number = 121;
let rev = 0;
let last_numb = 0;
let temp = number;
while(number > 0){
    last_numb = number % 10;
    number = Math.floor(number / 10);
    rev = rev * 10 + last_numb; 
}
if(temp == rev)
    console.log("the number is a palindrome");
else
    console.log("the number is not a palindrome");
```

Comment: Could you add a link of maybe where we could read the mathematics that support this answer? this is a really great answer...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive solution, in case anyone is interested, without the accumulator.

```
public boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
    if (x < 0) x = -1 * x;
    return x == recursive(x);
}

public int reverseDigits(int r) {
    if (r == 0) return 0;
    return (r % 10) * (int) Math.pow(10, get10thPower(r)) + reverseDigits(r / 10);
}

public int get10thPower(int r) {
    int i = 0;
    while (r / 10 > 0) {
        i++;
        r /= 10;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
reverse = 0;
    remainder = 0;
    count = 0;
    while (number > reverse)
    {
        remainder = number % 10;
        reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
        number = number / 10;
        count++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(count);
    if (reverse == number)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your number is a palindrome");
    }
    else
    {
        number = number * 10 + remainder;
        if (reverse == number)
            Console.WriteLine("your number is a palindrome");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("your number is not a palindrome");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution usings lists as stacks in python :

```
def isPalindromicNum(n):
    """
        is 'n' a palindromic number?
    """
    ns = list(str(n))
    for n in ns:
        if n != ns.pop():
            return False
    return True
```

popping the stack only considers the rightmost side of the number for comparison and it fails fast to reduce checks

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Numbers
 {
   public static void main(int givenNum)
   { 
       int n= givenNum
       int rev=0;

       while(n>0)
       {
          //To extract the last digit
          int digit=n%10;

          //To store it in reverse
          rev=(rev*10)+digit;

          //To throw the last digit
          n=n/10;
      }

      //To check if a number is palindrome or not
      if(rev==givenNum)
      { 
         System.out.println(givenNum+"is a palindrome ");
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.pritnln(givenNum+"is not a palindrome");
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let isPalindrome (n:int) =
   let l1 = n.ToString() |> List.ofSeq |> List.rev
   let rec isPalindromeInt l1 l2 =
       match (l1,l2) with
       | (h1::rest1,h2::rest2) -> if (h1 = h2) then isPalindromeInt rest1 rest2 else false
       | _ -> true
   isPalindromeInt l1 (n.ToString() |> List.ofSeq)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
checkPalindrome(int number)
{
    int lsd, msd,len;
    len = log10(number);
    while(number)
    {
        msd = (number/pow(10,len)); // "most significant digit"
        lsd = number%10; // "least significant digit"
        if(lsd==msd)
        {
            number/=10; // change of LSD
            number-=msd*pow(10,--len); // change of MSD, due to change of MSD
            len-=1; // due to change in LSD
            } else {return 1;}
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bad, bad solution. Log10 is a really slow, floating-point operation. Do not use this.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive way, not very efficient, just provide an option

(Python code)

```
def isPalindrome(num):
    size = len(str(num))
    demoninator = 10**(size-1)
    return isPalindromeHelper(num, size, demoninator)

def isPalindromeHelper(num, size, demoninator):
    """wrapper function, used in recursive"""
    if size <=1:
        return True
    else:       
        if num/demoninator != num%10:
            return False
        # shrink the size, num and denominator
        num %= demoninator
        num /= 10
        size -= 2
        demoninator /=100
        return isPalindromeHelper(num, size, demoninator)
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the easest thing would be to find the opposit number and compare the two:

```
int max =(int)(Math.random()*100001);

    int i;
    int num = max; //a var used in the tests
    int size; //the number of digits in the original number
    int opos = 0; // the oposite number
    int nsize = 1;

    System.out.println(max);

    for(i = 1; num>10; i++)
    {
        num = num/10;
    }

    System.out.println("this number has "+i+" digits");

    size = i; //setting the digit number to a var for later use



    num = max;

    for(i=1;i<size;i++)
    {
        nsize *=10;
    }


    while(num>1)
    {
        opos += (num%10)*nsize;
        num/=10;
        nsize/=10;
    }

    System.out.println("and the number backwards is "+opos);

    if (opos == max )
    {
        System.out.println("palindrome!!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("aint no palindrome!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print('!* To Find Palindrome Number') 

def Palindrome_Number():

            n = input('Enter Number to check for palindromee')  
            m=n 
            a = 0  

    while(m!=0):  
        a = m % 10 + a * 10    
        m = m / 10    

    if( n == a):    
        print('%d is a palindrome number' %n)
    else:
        print('%d is not a palindrome number' %n)
```

just call back the functions

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way.

```
class Palindrome_Number{
    void display(int a){
        int count=0;
        int n=a;
        int n1=a;
        while(a>0){
            count++;
            a=a/10;
        }
        double b=0.0d;
        while(n>0){
            b+=(n%10)*(Math.pow(10,count-1));
            count--;
            n=n/10;
        }
        if(b==(double)n1){
            System.out.println("Palindrome number");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Not a palindrome number");            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code possibly solves the problem, please explain how and why this code helps. Answers are not only for the original poster on this site, but for everybody who reads this thread in the future (who can be a beginner too).

Answer (score 0):

I went with the regular approach by converting number to string and then further converting string to charArray.
Traversing through charArray and find if number at positions are equal or not.
Note-: Not reversing the string.

```
public bool IsPalindrome(int num)
{
    string st = num.ToString();
    char[] arr = st.ToCharArray();
    int len = arr.Length;
    if (len <= 1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == arr[len - 1])
        {
            if (i >= len)
            {
                return true;
            }
            len--;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the solutions posted here reverses the integer and stores it in a variable which uses extra space which is `O(n)`, but here is a solution with `O(1)` space.

```
def isPalindrome(num):
    if num < 0:
        return False
    if num == 0:
        return True
    from math import log10
    length = int(log10(num))
    while length > 0:
        right = num % 10
        left = num / 10**length
        if right != left:
            return False
        num %= 10**length
        num /= 10
        length -= 2
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = int(raw_input())
list_num = list(str(num))
if list_num[::-1] == list_num:
    print "Its a palindrome"
else:
    print "Its not a palindrom"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best answer, and I'm new at programming. (it's in java)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Palin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random randInt = new Random();

        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = kbd.nextInt(); //# of test cases;
        String[] arrPalin = new String[t]; //array of inputs;
        String[] nextPalin = new String[t];
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            arrPalin[i] = String.valueOf(randInt.nextInt(2147483646) + 1);
            System.out.println(arrPalin[i]);
        }

        final long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            nextPalin[i] = (unmatcher(incrementer(switcher(match(arrPalin[i])))));
        }

        final long duration = System.nanoTime() - startTime;

        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            System.out.println(nextPalin[i]);
        }

        System.out.println(duration);

    }

    public static String match(String N) {
        int length = N.length();

        //Initialize a string with length of N
        char[] chars = new char[length];
        Arrays.fill(chars, '0');

        int count = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if ((i%2) == 0) { //at i = even.
                if (i == 0) {
                    chars[i] = N.charAt(i);
                } else
                    chars[i] = N.charAt(i/2);
            } else //at i = odd
                chars[i] = N.charAt(length - count);
                count++;
        }

        return String.valueOf(chars);
    }

    public static String switcher(String N) {
        int length = N.length();
        char[] chars = new char[length];
        Arrays.fill(chars, '0');

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                if ((i % 2) == 0) {
                    chars[i] = N.charAt(i);
                } else if ((i % 2) != 0) {
                    chars[i] = N.charAt(i - 1);
                }
            }
            if (i == 0) {
                chars[0] = N.charAt(0);
            }
        }
        return String.valueOf(chars);
    }

    public static String incrementer(String N) {
        int length = N.length();
        char[] chars = new char[length];
        Arrays.fill(chars, '0');

        char[] newN = N.toCharArray();

        String returnVal;

        int numOne, numTwo;

        if ((length % 2) == 0) {
            numOne = N.charAt(length-1);
            numTwo = N.charAt(length-2);
            newN[length-1] = (char)(numOne+1);
            newN[length-2] = (char)(numTwo+1);
            returnVal = String.valueOf(newN);
        } else {
            numOne = N.charAt(length-1);
            newN[length-1] = (char)(numOne+1);
            returnVal = String.valueOf(newN);
        }
        return returnVal;
    }

    public static String unmatcher(String N) {
        int length = N.length();
        char[] chars = new char[length];
        Arrays.fill(chars, '0');
        char[] newN = N.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (((i % 2) == 0) && (i != 0)) { // for i > 0, even
                    newN[i / 2] = N.charAt(i);
                } else if ((i % 2) == 0 && (i == 0)) { // for i = 0
                    newN[0] = N.charAt(0);
                }
            }
        for (int i = (length/2); i < length; i++) {
            newN[i] = newN[Math.abs(i - (length - 1))];
        }

        return String.valueOf(newN);
    }


}
```

So for this code, input a number (I did random numbers of how many I want), 
it will convert, for example the input is 172345 to 157423. Then it will change it to 117722, then if even make it 117733, if odd do the same for the only the last digit. Then make it 173371. It's not specifically finding a palindrome, but it's finding the next highest palindrome number.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PalindromePrime   {
     private static int g ,n =0,i,m ; 
     
     private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField;
     

     static String b ="";
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );  
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.print(" Please Inter Data : "); 
        g = scanner.nextInt();
        
        System.out.print(" Please Inter Data 2  : "); 
        m = scanner.nextInt();  
        
        count(g,m);     
    }   

    public static    int count(int L, int R) {
        int resultNum = 0;
    
        for( i= L ; i<= R ;i++){
            int count= 0 ;
            for( n = i ; n >=1 ;n -- ){
                if(i%n==0){             
                    count = count + 1 ;
                //  System.out.println("  Data : \n "  +count );    
                }       
            }
            if(count == 2)
            {   
                //b = b +i + "" ;
                
            String ss=  String .valueOf(i);
            //  System.out.print("\n" +i );
                if(isPalindrome(i))
                {
                //0 System.out.println("Number : " + i + " is   a palindrome");
                
                        //number2[b] = Integer.parseInt(number_ayy[b]);
                        
                    //String s = String .valueOf(i);
                    //System.out.printf("123456", s);
                    resultNum++;
                }
                else{
                    //*System.out.println("Number : " + i + " is Not  a palindrome");
                }
                //System.out.println("  Data : \n " +ss.length()  );    
            }
        //  palindrome(i);
        }
        
    //  System.out.print("  Data  : "); 
    //  System.out.println("  Data : \n "  +b ); 
        return resultNum;
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static boolean isPalindrome(int number  ) {
        int p = number; // ประกาศ  p เป็น int ให้เท่ากับ number ของ ตัวที่ มาจาก method 
        int r = 0; //ประกาศ r เป็น int โดยให้มีค่าเรื่องต้นเท่ากับ 0 
        int w = 0 ;
        while (p != 0) {  // เงื่อนไข While ถ้า p ไม่เท่ากับ 0  เช่น  2!= 0 จริง  เข้า  
             w = p % 10; // ประกาศตัว แปร W ให้ เท่ากับค่า p ที่มาจาก parramiter ให้ & mod กับ  10 คือ เช่น  2 % 10 = 2 ; w= 2 ; 3% 10 ; w =3
           r = r * 10 + w;  // (ให้  R ที่มาจาก การประกาศค่ตัวแปร แล้ว * 10) + w  จะมาจากค่า w = p % 10; ที่ mod ไว้  เช่น 0*10 + 2 = 2 
           p = p / 10;  //แล้วใช้ p ที่จมาจากตัว paramiter แล้วมาหาร  10  เพราะถ้าไม่มี ก็จะสามารถพิมพ์ค่าออกมาได้  || ทำไงก็ได้ให้เป็น 0  และเอามาแทนค่ตัวต่อไป 
        }

        // 1 วนวูปเช็คว่า   (p != 0) หรือไม่   โดย  p มาจาก p = number ที่รับมา 
        // 2 r = (r * 10) + (p%10) ;  
        
        //3   p = p /10 ; เพื่อเช็ค  ว่าให้มันเป็น 0 เพื่อหลุด Loop 
        if (number == r) {
            // for(int count = 0 ; count <i ;count ++){
        String s1 = String.valueOf(i);     
        
            //countLines(s1);
            System.out.println("Number : " + "'"+s1 +"'"+"  is   a palindrome");

            return true; //เรียก return ไป 
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    public static int countLines(String str)
    {
        if (str == null || str.length() == 0)
            return 0;
        int lines = 1;
        int len = str.length();
        for( int pos = 0; pos < len; pos++) {
            char c = str.charAt(pos);
            if( c == '\r' ) {
                System.out.println("Line 0 : " + "'"+str );
                
                lines++;
                if ( pos+1 < len && str.charAt(pos+1) == '\n' )
                    
                    System.out.println("Line : " + "'"+str );
                    
                  pos++;
            } else if( c == '\n' ) {
                lines++;
                
                System.out.println("Line 2 : " + "'"+str );
            }
        }
        return lines;
    }
    
    public static int countLines1(String sd) throws IOException {
        LineNumberReader lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(new StringReader(sd));
        int count = 0 ;
        System.out.printf("Line  : " , count = count + 1 );
        lineNumberReader.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        return lineNumberReader.getLineNumber();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = input.nextInt();
    int number = num;
    int reversenum = 0;
    while (num != 0)
    {
        reversenum = reversenum * 10;
        reversenum = reversenum + num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
    }

    if (number == reversenum)
        System.out.println("The reverse number is " + reversenum + "\nThen the number is palindrome.");
    else
        System.out.println("The reverse number is " + reversenum + "\nThen the number is not palindrome.");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code converts int to String and then checks if the string is pallindrome. The advantage is that it is fast, the disadvantage being that it converts int to String thereby compromising with the perfect solution to question.

```
static int pallindrome=41012;
static String pallindromer=(Integer.toString(pallindrome));
static int length=pallindromer.length();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    pallindrome(0);
    System.out.println("It's a pallindrome");
}

static void pallindrome(int index){
    if(pallindromer.charAt(index)==pallindromer.charAt(length-(index+1))){
        if(index<length-1){
            pallindrome(++index);
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Not a pallindrome");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the leading zeros are ignored. Following is an implementation:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
vector<int>digits;
stack<int>digitsRev;
int d,number;
bool isPal=1;//initially assuming the number is palindrome
int main()
{
    cin>>number;
    if(number<10)//if it is a single digit number than it is palindrome
    {
        cout<<"PALINDROME"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    //if the number is greater than or equal to 10
    while(1)
    {
        d=number%10;//taking each digit
        number=number/10;
        //vector and stack will pick the digits
        //in reverse order to each other
        digits.push_back(d);
        digitsRev.push(d);
        if(number==0)break;
    }
    int index=0;
    while(!digitsRev.empty())
    {
        //Checking each element of the vector and the stack
        //to see if there is any inequality.
        //And which is equivalent to check each digit of the main
        //number from both sides
        if(digitsRev.top()!=digits[index++])
        {
            cout<<"NOT PALINDROME"<<endl;
            isPal=0;
            break;
        }
        digitsRev.pop();
    }
    //If the digits are equal from both sides than the number is palindrome
    if(isPal==1)cout<<"PALINDROME"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: (Down-voter please comment.)(I dislike this for being a code-only answer presenting uncommented code.)

Comment: Hi @greybeard is the answer self-explanatory now?

Comment: I think the workings of the code are explained sufficiently in [revision 5](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39803062/5). There's always room for improvement - do you know [Code Review@SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: @greybeard I was not too much aware of this community before (had an account there, but not an active participant as I never carefully noticed that community's purpose). I have skimmed through content from your provided link. It sounds interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution in java  :

```
private static boolean ispalidrome(long n) {
        return getrev(n, 0L) == n;
    }

    private static long getrev(long n, long initvalue) {
        if (n <= 0) {
            return initvalue;
        }
        initvalue = (initvalue * 10) + (n % 10);
        return getrev(n / 10, initvalue);
    }
```

Comment: What language is supposed to give meaning to those (uncommented) statements? Can `isPalindrome(123454328)` result in arithmetic overflow?

Comment: (Hrmjah, counting to ten is not as easy as 1-2-3:) What about 1234554328?

Comment: this is a fault due to  reverse number that surpass max int value =2^31-1 , so just to get correct result to the issue is to convert all entry to long and much better to bigInteger

Answer (score 0):

Simply get the digit count of the number via Math functions and then iterate by using '/' and '%' operations as follows. After x = (x % divider) / 10, we should divide divider by 100 since we made 2 zero operations.

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
            if (x < 0) return false;
            if (x < 10) return true;

            int numDigits = (int)(Math.log10(x)+1);
            int divider = (int) (Math.pow(10, numDigits - 1));
            for (int i = 0; i < numDigits / 2; i++) {
                if (x / divider != x % 10)
                    return false;
                x = (x % divider) / 10;
                divider /= 100;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the answer in swift. 
It reads number from left and right side and compare them if they are same.
Doing this way we will never face a problem of integer overflow ***(which can occure on reversing number method)*** as we are not creating another number.

**Steps:**

1. Get length of number
2. Loop from length + 1(first) --> 0
3. Get ith digit & get last digit
4. if both digits are not equal return false as number is not palindrome
5. i --
6. discard last digit from num (num = num / 10)
7. end of loo return true

   ```
   func isPalindrom(_ input: Int) -> Bool {
          if input < 0 {
               return false
           }

           if input < 10 {
               return true
           }

           var num = input
           let length = Int(log10(Float(input))) + 1
           var i = length

           while i > 0 && num > 0 {

               let ithDigit = (input / Int(pow(10.0, Double(i) - 1.0)) ) % 10
               let r = Int(num % 10)

               if ithDigit != r {
                   return false
               }

               num = num / 10
               i -= 1
           }

           return true
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
        int newX = x;
        int newNum = 0;
        boolean result = false;
        if (x >= 0) {
            while (newX >= 10) {
                newNum = newNum+newX % 10;
                newNum = newNum * 10;
                newX = newX / 10;
            }
            newNum += newX;

            if(newNum==x) {
            result = true;
            }
            else {
                result=false;
            }
        }

        else {

            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
        if (isNegative(x))
            return false;

        boolean isPalindrome = reverseNumber(x) == x ? true : false;
        return isPalindrome;
    }

    private boolean isNegative(int x) {
        if (x < 0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public int reverseNumber(int x) {

        int reverseNumber = 0;

        while (x > 0) {
            int remainder = x % 10;
            reverseNumber = reverseNumber * 10 + remainder;
            x = x / 10;
        }

        return reverseNumber;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my Java code. Basically comparing the the first and last value of the string and next inner value pair and so forth.

```
    /*Palindrome number*/
    String sNumber = "12321";
    int l = sNumber.length(); // getting the length of sNumber. In this case its 5
    boolean flag = true;
    for (int i = 0; i <= l; ++i) {
        if (sNumber.charAt(i) != sNumber.charAt((l--) -1)) { //comparing the first and the last values of the string
            System.out.println(sNumber +" is not a palindrome number");
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
        //l--; // to reducing the length value by 1 
    }
    if (flag) {
        System.out.println(sNumber +" is a palindrome number");
    }
```

Comment: What question does this answer? Not `How do I check if a number is a palindrome?` where `making the number a string` is excepted.

Answer (score -1):

Dammit, I’m mad! 
http://www.palindromelist.net/palindromes-d/
Single steps example: is 332 a palindromic number?

```C#
n = 332
q = n / 10 = 33
r = n - 10 * q = 2
r > 0
r != q
n = q = 33
n > r
q = n / 10 = 3
r -= q = 4294967295
r *= 10 = 4294967286
r += n = 23
r != n
r != q
n = q = 3
n > r ? No, so 332 isn't a palindromic number.
```

Overflow isn't a problem either.
Two divisions were necessary, in code (C#) they're done with multiplications.
A n-digit number: ~n/2 divisions!

```cs
const ulong c0 = 0xcccccccdUL;
static bool isPal(uint n)
{
    if (n < 10) return true;
    uint q = (uint)(c0 * n >> 35);
    uint r = n - 10 * q;
    if (r == 0) return false;
    if (r == q) return true;
    n = q;
    while (n > r)
    {
        q = (uint)(c0 * n >> 35);
        r -= q;
        r *= 10;
        r += n;
        if (r == n || r == q) return true;
        n = q;
    }
    return false;
}
```

There are 142948 palindromic numbers < 2^32, their sum is 137275874705916.

```C#
using System;
class Program
{
    static void Main()  // take a break
    {
        uint n, c; var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        n = ~0u; c = 0; sw.Restart(); while (n > 0) if (isPal0(n--)) c++;
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed + " " + c);                  // 76 s
        n = ~0u; c = 0; sw.Restart(); while (n > 0) if (isPal1(n--)) c++;
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed + " " + c);                  // 42 s
        n = ~0u; c = 0; sw.Restart(); while (n > 0) if (isPal2(n--)) c++;
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed + " " + c);                  // 31 s
        Console.Read();
    }

    static bool isPal0(uint u)
    {
        uint n = u, rev = 0;
        while (n > 0) { uint dig = n % 10; rev = rev * 10 + dig; n /= 10; }
        return u == rev;
    }

    static bool isPal1(uint u)
    {
        uint n = u, r = 0;
        while (n >= 10) r = n + (r - (n /= 10)) * 10;
        return u == 10 * r + n;
    }

    static bool isPal2(uint n)
    {
        if (n < 10) return true;
        uint q = n / 10, r = n - 10 * q;
        if (r == 0 || r == q) return r > 0;
        while ((n = q) > r)
        {
            q /= 10; r -= q; r *= 10; r += n;
            if (r == n || r == q) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This one seems to be faster.

```C#
using System;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        uint n, c; var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        n = ~0u; c = 0; sw.Restart(); while (n > 0) if (isPal(n--)) c++;
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed + " " + c);                 // 21 s
        Console.Read();
    }

    static bool isPal(uint n)
    {
        return n < 100 ? n < 10 || n % 11 == 0 :
              n < 1000 ? /*          */ n / 100 == n % 10 :
             n < 10000 ? n % 11 == 0 && n / 1000 == n % 10 && isP(n) :
            n < 100000 ? /*          */ n / 10000 == n % 10 && isP(n) :
           n < 1000000 ? n % 11 == 0 && n / 100000 == n % 10 && isP(n) :
          n < 10000000 ? /*          */ n / 1000000 == n % 10 && isP(n) :
         n < 100000000 ? n % 11 == 0 && n / 10000000 == n % 10 && isP(n) :
        n < 1000000000 ? /*          */ n / 100000000 == n % 10 && isP(n) :
                         n % 11 == 0 && n / 1000000000 == n % 10 && isP(n);
    }

    static bool isP(uint n)
    {
        uint q = n / 10, r = n - 10 * q;
        do { n = q; q /= 10; r -= q; r *= 10; r += n; } while (r < q);
        return r == q || r == n;
    }
}
```

With an almost balanced binary search spaghetti tree.

```C#
using System;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        uint n, c; var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        n = c = 0; sw.Restart(); while (n < ~0u) if (isPal(n++)) c++;
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed + " " + c);              // 17 s
        Console.Read();
    }

    static bool isPal(uint n)
    {
        return n < 1000000 ? n < 10000 ? n < 1000 ? n < 100 ?
        n < 10 || n % 11 == 0 : n / 100 == n % 10 :
        n / 1000 == n % 10 && isP(n) : n < 100000 ?
        n / 10000 == n % 10 && isP(n) :
        n / 100000 == n % 10 && isP(n) :
        n < 100000000 ? n < 10000000 ?
        n / 1000000 == n % 10 && isP(n) :
        n % 11 == 0 && n / 10000000 == n % 10 && isP(n) :
        n < 1000000000 ? n / 100000000 == n % 10 && isP(n) :
        n % 11 == 0 && n / 1000000000 == n % 10 && isP(n);
    }

    static bool isP(uint n)
    {
        uint q = n / 10, r = n - 10 * q;
        do { n = q; q /= 10; r -= q; r *= 10; r += n; } while (r < q);
        return r == q || r == n;
    }
}
```

Unbalanced upside down.

```C#
using System;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        uint n, c; var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        n = c = 0; sw.Restart(); while (n < ~0u) if (isPal(n++)) c++;
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed + " " + c);              // 16 s
        Console.Read();
    }

    static bool isPal(uint n)
    {
        return
        n > 999999999 ? n % 11 == 0 && n / 1000000000 == n % 10 && isP(n) :
        n > 99999999 ? n / 100000000 == n % 10 && isP(n) :
        n > 9999999 ? n % 11 == 0 && n / 10000000 == n % 10 && isP(n) :
        n > 999999 ? n / 1000000 == n % 10 && isP(n) :
        n > 99999 ? n % 11 == 0 && n / 100000 == n % 10 && isP(n) :
        n > 9999 ? n / 10000 == n % 10 && isP(n) :
        n > 999 ? n % 11 == 0 && n / 1000 == n % 10 && isP(n) :
        n > 99 ? n / 100 == n % 10 :
        n < 10 || n % 11 == 0;
    }

    static bool isP(uint n)
    {
        uint q = n / 10, r = n - 10 * q;
        do { n = q; q /= 10; r -= q; r *= 10; r += n; } while (r < q);
        return r == q || r == n;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to provide a map for your answer upfront. Please make the direct answer to the question the first entry.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best solution provided here https://stackoverflow.com/a/199203/5704551

The coding implementation of this solution can be something like:

```
var palindromCheck(nums) = () => {
    let str = x.toString()
    // + before str is quick syntax to cast String To Number.
    return nums === +str.split("").reverse().join("")  
}
```

Comment: The question `[excepts] the algorithm of making the number a string and then reversing the string`.

Answer (score -2):

One line python code :

```
def isPalindrome(number):
    return True if str(number) == ''.join(reversed(str(number))) else False
```

Comment: The question `[excepts] the algorithm of making the number a string and then reversing the string`.

Answer (score -2):

Personally I do it this way, and there's no overlap; the code stops checking for matching characters in the correct spot whether the string has an even or odd length. Some of the other methods posted above will attempt to match one extra time when it doesn't need to.

If we use length/2, it will still work but it will do one additional check that it doesn't need to do. For instance, "pop" is 3 in length. 3/2 = 1.5, so it will stop checking when i = 2(since 1<1.5 it will check when i = 1 as well) but we need it to stop at 0, not one. The first "p" is in position 0, and it will check itself against length-1-0(current position) which is the last "p" in position 2, and then we are left with the center letter that needs no checking. When we do length/2 we stop at 1, so what happens is an extra check is performed with i being on the 1 position(the "o") and compares it to itself (length-1-i).

```
// Checks if our string is palindromic.
var ourString = "A Man, /.,.()^&*A Plan, A Canal__-Panama!";
isPalin(ourString);

function isPalin(string) {
// Make all lower case for case insensitivity and replace all spaces, underscores and non-words.
string = string.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, "").replace(/\W/g,"").replace(/_/g,"");
for(i=0; i<=Math.floor(string.length/2-1); i++) {
      if(string[i] !== string[string.length-1-i]) {
        console.log("Your string is not palindromic!");
        break;
      } else if(i === Math.floor(string.length/2-1)) {
        console.log("Your string is palindromic!");
      }
    }
}
```

https://repl.it/FNVZ/1

Comment: What question does this answer? Not `How do I check if a number is a palindrome?` where `making the number a string` is excepted.

Answer (score -2):

This solution is quite efficient, since I am using StringBuilder which means that the StringBuilder Class is implemented as a mutable sequence of characters. This means that you append new Strings or chars onto a StringBuilder.

```java
 public static boolean isPal(String ss){
   StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(ss);
   stringBuilder.reverse();
   return ss.equals(stringBuilder.toString());
 }
```

Comment: The question `[excepts] the algorithm of making the number a string and then reversing the string`.