# Palindrome is not working

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I check if a number is a palindrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199184/how-do-i-check-if-a-number-is-a-palindrome)

Hello All i want to make program to check whether palindrome number or not when user input the number. But my work does not work at all... Can you guys help me...

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 0, j = 0 ;

            int numbers =Convert.ToInt32( Console.ReadLine());
            i = numbers % 10;
            do
            {
               j = numbers / 10;

            }
            while (j < 10);

            if (i == j)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" this is palindrome number");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("not a palindrome");
      }
```

Comment: School assignment ?

Comment: Do you understand the method you should be using, and are having trouble with getting the computer to do that, or are you asking for the steps you need in order to work out whether a number is a palindromic?

Comment: What are you struggling with? Exactly?

Comment: why not just reverse the input string and compare it with the original ?

Comment: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/72744

Comment: @Lars Tackmann: Because 1210 is not a numerical palindrome of 121?

Comment: @phresnel and the reversal of the the input string "1210" is "0121" not 121

Comment: @Rune, but the answer said palindrome **number**, so it wouldn't include leading zeros.

Comment: hmmm ... so if the input has trailing Zero you can straight away say "not a palindrome" ! !

Comment: @V4Vendetta: What's with the number "0"? But apart from this special case, I conjure you're right.

Comment: @phresnel indeed the case for all single digit nums

Comment: @George I don't get you're comment. The solution Lars gave will yield the correct answer for palindrom numbers in the case questioned by phresnel. (An input of "01210" would however fail the test in terms of strict numeric values

Comment: @Rune, exactly, it would fail if the string input had leading zeros as you point out.

Answer (score 4):

The quickest way is to [reverse the string](http://www.dotnetperls.com/reverse-string) and compare it to the original. You don't really need the integer conversion.

You may want to filter or correct the user's input by stripping leading zeroes (i.e. in `010`). For example : `string number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()).ToString();`

Comment: So 10 is a numeric palindrome of 1?

Comment: To me it's not. If you reverse the string, you end up comparing `1` and `01`, so it's not equal. What is the problem ?

Comment: @kbok, if you reversed the string you'd get "01". The solution could be to convert to number, then back to string, then compare.

Comment: If input is e.g. 010, then there of course exists a string-palindrome, but not a numeric one: "010" = the integer 10. And the integer 10 is not a palindrome. But just reversing and comparing strings would allow 10 to be a numeric palindrome by prefixing it with 0.

Comment: `010` is invalid input. It does not affects the validity of this solution.

Comment: @kbok: Though you would have to consider the special case "0".

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to convert it to integer.
You can check it from the string.

Take the first character and the last character compare those .

Iterate the first pointer +1 and the last pointer -1 then compare.

Continue this process upto you are in middle of the string.

Comment: although if this is [tag:homework] then it probably needs to be done with a number.

Comment: So 10 is a numeric palindrome of 1?

Comment: @Carra: Needs to check for special case "0" first.

Comment: @phresnel I don’t understand your (repeated) comment. How is this an issue in this suggested solution? Reversing the string `"10"` yields `"01"` which can be directly compared to the original string. I don’t particularly like the string comparison solution but your objection is misguided.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: If the input is "01", which is accepted as the integer 1 in the countries I know, then using just string reversing and then comparison would tell that "1" is not a numeric palindrome of "01".

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: I realise my comments miss a trailing zero. Should have been "So 10 is a valid palindrome of 10?" (see "010").

Answer (score 0):

[a disscussion](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=56285)

[palindrome check](http://www.electrofriends.com/source_codes/C/num_pali.html)

[C# code to check palindrome](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&cp=15&gs_id=1y&xhr=t&q=c+code+to+check+palindrome&pf=p&sclient=psy&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=C#+code+to+chek&aq=0l&aqi=g-l4g-lv1&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=661c0b1152c259b4&biw=1024&bih=577)

You can follow these links .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
void main()
{
     long int n, num, rev = 0, dig;
     clrscr();
     printf("\n\n\t ENTER A NUMBER...: ");
     scanf("%ld", &num);
     n = num;
     while(num>0)
     {
          dig = num % 10;
          rev = rev * 10 + dig;
          num = num / 10;
     }
     if (n == rev)
           printf("\n\t GIVEN NUMBER IS A PALINDROME");
     else
           printf("\n\t GIVEN NUMBER NOT A PALINDROME");
     getch();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not how we do things here on StackOverflow. Posting a link to a Google search **that doesn't work** but would supposedly *find a piece of code that does this* is hardly an helpful answer.

Comment: But those links can be helpful.

Comment: What links? All I get from that link is a blank page (and I checked, I'm not the only one). And you could post one of those *helpful links* instead. Or post some helpful content derived from them.

Comment: ops, there was some problem pasting that link, i have edited that post.

Answer (score 0):

First of all by converting the digits to an `Int32`, the number of digits a user can enter are limited.

By using the modulo operation, the `i` variable will contain the last digit of the entered number.

By dividing the number by 10, `j` should eventually contain the first digit entered. However you aren't dividing it "until `j` is smaller than 10", but you're dividing it "while `j` is smaller than 10", effectively making the contents of `j` depend on the number of digits entered.

Even if you would fix the `while` condition, this code will only check the first and last digit, making it function only for 1, 2 and 3 digit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something like this:

```
        bool isPalindrome = true;
        string s = "300212003";
        for (int i = 0; i < (s.Length / 2); i++)
        {
            if (s[i] != s[s.Length - i - 1])
            {
                isPalindrome = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(isPalindrome);
```

It's faster than reverting a string and comparing it, only need O(n/2) operations.

Comment: This suffers from leading zeros.

Answer (score -1):

Something is palindrome when you can read it either way, so when the reverse is the same as the original. 
So just reverse your input string and compare it to the original.

Comment: So 10 is a numeric palindrome of 1?

Comment: No its not? "10" != "01" Palindromes dont have to be numeric, you should compare strings.

Comment: they don't have to, but the question reads: "check whether palindrome number or not"

Comment: And in my answer is suggest casting them to strings, eventhough they are numeric. When you dont do any calculations with the number, why store it as one?

Comment: Where exactly in your answer is the "casting" part? Your answer was specifically "So just reverse your input string".

Comment: Little update: My comment should have been "10 is a valid numeric palindrome of 10?" ("010").