# Check whether an integer is palindrome or not in PHP?

Tags: php, palindrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I check if a number is a palindrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199184/how-do-i-check-if-a-number-is-a-palindrome)

If an integer is to not allowed to be treated a string and typecasting is not allowed, how can we figure out whether the number is palindrome or not(in PHP)?

The program which I have come up with is:

```
function checkPalindrome($number){
    $reverse_number = 0;
    $number_backup  = $number;
    while($number > 0){
      $reverse_number = $reverse_number * 10 + $number % 10;
      $number /= 10;
    }
    return $reverse_number == $number_backup;
}
```

At step "$number/=10", the result generated won't be integer which is creating the problem.

Comment: Where do the not-string, no-typecasting constraints come from? Is this a [tag:homework] question?

Comment: Is this a question for school? Why else would these restrictions apply?

Comment: *maybe* it's *just* for practice ;)

Comment: This was a question asked in an interview.

Comment: In an interview? You are better off not getting the job... That's just a jerky thing to do to someone. (unless it is a code example you are meant to do and send back, in which case stop cheating.)

Comment: Its over and not getting job anyway:). Just curious to know the answer now.

Comment: @Wiseguy : Its not a duplicate. In PHP that won't work.

Comment: The algorithm is language-agnostic, so just add dollar signs or whatever's necessary to make it PHP.

Comment: @Wiseguy: Try it. It doesn't work. The difference is that in PHP, you have to do: `$num = ($num - $dig) / 10;`.

Comment: Or `$num = floor($num/10);` would work as well. I don't think that would violate the rules of "no typecasting."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are not allowed to typecast and string-handling is forbidden, you need to do some extra calculations:

```
while($number > 0){
  $lsd = $number % 10;
  $reverse_number = $reverse_number * 10 + $lsd;
  $number = ($number - $lsd) / 10;
}
```

Comment: Great! This solves the problem.

Comment: Cole, *least significant digit* :-)