# Method to check if number is symmetric in Java

Tags: java

I need help with a method to check if a number is symmetric, so from what I understand I need to check equality between all the numbers and to make sure there is no different number amounts them...right?

This is my code:

```
public boolean isSemetric (int number) {

    int temp;
    boolean answer = true;

    while (number != 0) {

        temp = number % 10;
        number /= 10;

        if (temp != (number%10)) {
        answer = false;
        } else { 
            answer = true;
        }

    }

    return answer;

}
```

I'm kind of new to programming so be forgiven to my code :/

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. The last else part seems redundant though.

Comment: By a symmetric number you mean palindrome?

Comment: Don't you want to return immediately if the number isn't symmetric?

Comment: "I don't see anything wrong with your code". What right do you see? This code seems to always return false. Unless number=0.

Comment: yes i guess they mean palindrome...so 555 would be symmetric and 535 is symmetric, but 5345 isn't symmetric...now i see that it's totally wrong :/ @CMate

Comment: You are checking whether every 2 following digits are the same. That is not the definition of palindrome. And you are also checking that incorrectly, because you do not break the loop if a mismatch is found. See peter.petrov's comment.

Comment: Check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199184/how-do-i-check-if-a-number-is-a-palindrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As peter.petrov pointed out in the comment section of your question, your method as it's written will always return `false`, except for when `number` is equal to 0.  The reason for this can be seen when you pass in a number like 111 and step through the code in a debugger.  The final iteration will fail because `number /= 10` will result in `0`, and `temp` will be `1`, which fails your test.

If you are indeed looking to identify palindromes, consider the following approach that should be simple to implement

```
  1. copy number into temp
  2. convert temp to a String, and reverse it (tmpStr)
  3. convert tmpStr back to an integer (reversedInt)
  4. compare number and reversedInt for equality
```

viola.  Not the most efficient algorithm, but its easy to understand and gets the job done.

Comment: I believe it's "voila"

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this (I don't want to use String here and I don't want to use local array variable for the digits).

```
    public static boolean isSymmetric (long number) {
        if (number == 0) return true;
        else if (number < 0) return false;
        long DEG_10 = (long)(Math.pow(10, (int)Math.log10(number)));

        while (number > 0){
            long dStart = number / DEG_10;
            long dEnd = number % 10;
            if (dStart != dEnd) return false;
            number = (number - dStart * DEG_10 - dEnd) / 10;
            DEG_10 /= 100;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat fixed up version of your code. However, it checks if all numbers are the same, e.g. 5555 or 111. 11211 would return false.

```
public boolean areAllDigitsTheSame (int number) {

    int temp;
    boolean answer = true;

    while (number >= 10) {

        temp = number % 10;
        number /= 10;

        if (temp != (number%10)) {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Edit: The [C++ answer in the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/199218/579344) works by constructing the reverse number gradually in the loop, and finally checking if they're the same. This is a similar to what you are doing.

Here's another version for fun:

```
public boolean isPalindrome (int number) {

    int reversedNumber = 0;
    while (number > 0) {

        int digit = number % 10;
        reversedNumber = reversedNumber*10 + digit;

        if (reversedNumber == number) { // odd number of digits
            return true;
        }

        number /= 10;

        if (reversedNumber == number) { // even number of digits
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest approach I can think of - Get the String value of the number, if the reverse is the same then it is symmetrical.

```
// Symmetry
public static boolean isSymmetric(int number) {
  String val = String.valueOf(number); // Get the string.
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(val);
  return (val.equals(sb.reverse().toString())); // if the reverse is the same...
}
```