# Creating a Palindrome identifier

Tags: java, palindrome

How can I add a statement that allows me to check if the credit card number inputted by the user is a palindrome? I am checking for the appropriate length already so how can i Input the new palindrome checker into this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DT18 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String number;
        Boolean debug = false;

        if (args.length == 0) { // no command line
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Please enter a Credit Card number to validate.");
            number = keyboard.next();
        } else { // command line input
            number = args[0];
        }


        if (debug) System.out.println("String Length " + number.length());


        if (number.length() < 10) {
            System.out.println("Not Valid");
        }


        int sum = 0;
        int oddDigit = 0;
        for (int i = number.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (debug) System.out.println("i = " + i);
            if ((Character.getNumericValue(number.charAt(i)) < 0) || (Character.getNumericValue(number.charAt(i)) > 9)) {
                System.out.println("Not Valid");
                break;
            }
            if (i % 2 == 0) { //Even Digit
                sum += Character.getNumericValue(number.charAt(i));
            } else { //Odd Digit
                oddDigit = (2 * Character.getNumericValue(number.charAt(i)));
                if (oddDigit > 9) oddDigit = (oddDigit % 10) + 1;
                sum += oddDigit;
            }
            if (debug) System.out.println(sum);
        }
        if (sum % 10 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Valid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Valid");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What does a palindrome have to do with Credit Card validation? Also, this question needs better tags. At the very least, add a Java tag and maybe something about input or credit card validation.

Comment: Just going the extra mile in this code. Trying to add something cool haha

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check string for palindrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138827/check-string-for-palindrome)

Answer (score 2):

From an answer I once gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29228689/1057429):

```
public boolean isPalindrom(int n) {
    return new StringBuilder("" + n).reverse().toString().equals("" + n);
}
```

Comment: `Integer.toString` is recommended over `"" + `

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg Thank you for your comment! I had no idea it has better performance. Can you post a link?

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg interesting, he says that it's "slightly less efficient". I'd appreciate to see some benchmarking around it. Seems like it's mainly a style issue...

Answer (score 1):

This post should give you for loop logic:

http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-program-check-palindrome

```
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
  String original, reverse = "";
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter a string to check if it is a palindrome");
  original = in.nextLine();

  int length = original.length();

  for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
     reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);

  if (original.equals(reverse))
     System.out.println("Entered string is a palindrome.");
  else
     System.out.println("Entered string is not a palindrome.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple function to check if a string is a palindrome or not.

```
 private static boolean checkPalindrome(String input) {
    int i = 0, j = input.length() - 1;
    for (; i < j; i++) {
        if (i == j) {
            return true;
        }
        if (input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(j)) {
            j--;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is a crude method; you may want to modify it according to your requirement, but it will get the job done in most of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked over the other answers and all of them have bad performance and working with `String` instead of just using the given number. So I'll add the version without conversion to `String`:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(int n) {
    int[] digits = new int[length(n)];

    for (int i = 0; n != 0; ++i) {
        digits[i] = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length / 2; ++i) {
        if (digits[i] != digits[digits.length - i - 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static int length(int n) {
    int len = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        ++len;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return len;
}
```

Not sure, if that's the best implementation, but I got rid of `String`s :-)