# Would a stingstream work to convert an int to a sting?

Tags: c++, stringstream

I recently read a question about turning strings to integers - ([Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c)).

I know what itoa is, but what are stringstreams and how are they used? I am trying to implement a way to tell if an integer is a "palindrome" and I would like to change each input to a string to find out if it is a palindrome. Thank you to anyone to answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stringstreams are one of three C++ style input/output buffers available through the c++ standard library: file streams, string streams and array streams, though array streams are deprecated. Just like file streams read to and from a file, string streams will read to and from a string.

Their operators are just like file streams, too: `operator>>` will read information into a variable using the source data from the stream to determine the result, and `operator<<` will place the data from the right-hand operand into the stringstream. Any function which operates on an `istream` will operate on an `istringstream` and similarly any function which operates on an `ostream` will operate on an `ostringstream`, since the stringstreams inherit from those respective base classes.

The internal buffer for the stringstreams can be accessed by calling their member function `str()` which [gets or sets the underlying string object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/str)

I've mostly seen input stringstreams used as a method of placing text data into variables when the original string was available only all at once, and when applying tokenization to specific parts of larger text data. Another use case could be passing in a string to a function which needs different information depending on the information in the string: [[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27ab71711fa81499)]:

```
void doDifferentThingsFromString(const std::string &str){
    std::string
        command;
    std::istringstream
        stream{str}; // construct an input string stream

    stream >> command;
    if(command == "line"){
        std::cout << stream.str() << '\n';
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "not line!\n";
    }
}

int main(){

    doDifferentThingsFromString("line Alice and \nBob were having an adventure.");
    doDifferentThingsFromString("well this won't print anything at all");

}
```

outputs

```
line Alice and 
Bob were having an adventure.
not line!
```

Though of course the second call did in fact print something--just not the supplied argument.

On the other hand, output stringstreams are useful for conversion of sequences of data into strings. Say you have an integer and a double and you want to display them reversed. Unfortunately, for some reason your compiler doesn't have the set of standard library functions for `to_string` implemented. Maybe you have another class, `Foo`, which is a bit more complicated to print, and you already have a printing function for it, and you don't want to write a string conversion function for just this little bit of code. Good news! you don't have to!

With an `ostringstream`, you can simply read data into your stream like you would with a file stream, then get the resulting string, and manipulate the string however you wish. [[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ea2615ff47a5837)]:

```
std::string reverse(const std::string &original){
    return std::string{original.rbegin(), original.rend()};
}  


void printReversed(int integer, double floatingPoint){
    std::ostringstream
        stream;

    stream << integer << ", " << floatingPoint;


    std::cout << reverse(stream.str()) << '\n';
}

template <typename Container_>
void printContainer(std::ostream &out, const Container_ &container){
    for(auto &&element : container){
        out << element << ", ";
    }
    out << "\n";
}


int main(){

    printReversed(17, 43.21);
    std::ostringstream
        stream;

    printContainer(stream, "never eat soggy waffles");

    std::cout << reverse(stream.str()) << "\n";
}
```

outputs

```
12.34 ,71

 , ,s ,e ,l ,f ,f ,a ,w ,  ,y ,g ,g ,o ,s ,  ,t ,a ,e ,  ,r ,e ,v ,e ,n
```

There is also a `stringstream` which operates like the `fstream` and allows both input and output operations. All three stringstream types have narrow and wide variants. More information is available on the wiki:

[`istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)
[`ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream)
[`stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)

Answer (score 0):

Stringstream is a stream just like cin or cout, but at the other end is memory rather than an IO device. It can probably be better explained by googling, but the first few that are likely to come up are

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/

and

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream

Using it to convert an integer to a string is simple:

```
std::string toString(int in)
{
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << in;
    return stream.str();
}
```

But it is more useful generalized a bit to handle a wider variety of inputs

```
template<class TYPE>
std::string toString(TYPE in)
{
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << in;
    return stream.str();
}
```

Converting the string back is also simple:

```
template<class TYPE>
TYPE fromString(std::string in)
{
    std::stringstream stream(in);
    TYPE rval;
    stream >> rval;
    return rval;
}
```

But what it is bad at is converting user input.  It won't tell you if the input string was "hamster". It will just return 0. This is not a problem for the OP's case, input was a number, but I generally recommend using [std::strtol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul). You can test the end parameter for the null character to see if the whole string was parsed.

As an aside, you don't need to convert the number to a string. [This is a very well examined problem with many, many solutions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199184/how-do-i-check-if-a-number-is-a-palindrome)